# What optimization problem is this?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

Minimize $$\sum_{i=1}^{m}w_i x_i$$ with $w_i \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge0}$, and $x_i \in \{0, 1\}$ subject to a set of $n$ conditions of the form $$\sum_{i\in S_k} x_i \equiv c_k \pmod{2}$$ for $S_k \subseteq \{1, \ldots, m\}$ and $1 \le k \le n$.

This seems very similar binary integer linear programming problem, except the conditions are modulo 2. I am wondering if this is a well-known optimization problem (or reducible to some well-known one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, you want $\sum_{i\in S_k} x_i - c_k  = 2r_k$ where $r_k$ is an integer decision variable. Hence, you have a problem with binary and integer variables, i.e., standard integer linear programming (reducible to a purely binary program if you wish).